# pyspark process expression in dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, eval, apache-spark-sql

I have salary of an employee and want to know on How many buckets does the salary falls  ?

```py
salary = 3000
```

Rules table

```
rule_id,condtion,bucket
1,salary>1000,'A'
2,salary>2000,'B'
3,salary>3000,'C'
4,salary>4000,'D'
5,salary>5000,'E'
```

from above two tables i want to produce below result

```
rule_id,condtion,bucket,result
1,salary>1000,'A',True
2,salary>2000,'B'True
3,salary>3000,'C',True
4,salary>4000,'D',False
5,salary>5000,'E',False
```

I tried with python and spark

```py
salary = 3000

rules_df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true').load('rule.csv')


validate = rules_df.withColumn('result',eval(rules_df.condtion))
```

for the above code i am getting below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3296, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-129-a813eeada424>", line 1, in <module>
    rules_df.withColumn('valid',eval(str(rules_df.condtion)))

  File "<string>", line 1
    Column<b'condtion'>
                      ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `udf` to do `eval` here:
here' the DataFrame:

```
+-------+-----------+------+
|rule_id|   condtion|bucket|
+-------+-----------+------+
|      1|salary>1000|   'A'|
|      2|salary>2000|   'B'|
|      3|salary>3000|   'C'|
|      4|salary>4000|   'D'|
|      5|salary>5000|   'E'|
+-------+-----------+------+
```

Now we define a `udf` to explicitly parse the column `condtion`:

```
salary = 3000
my_udf = F.udf(lambda c: eval(c, {'salary':salary}), BooleanType())
df = df.withColumn('result', my_udf('condtion'))
df.show()

+-------+-----------+------+------+
|rule_id|   condtion|bucket|result|
+-------+-----------+------+------+
|      1|salary>1000|   'A'|  true|
|      2|salary>2000|   'B'|  true|
|      3|salary>3000|   'C'| false|
|      4|salary>4000|   'D'| false|
|      5|salary>5000|   'E'| false|
+-------+-----------+------+------+
```

I am not sure how big is your `rule` table, but if it's not too big and 
if you are just trying to apply the rule table to single data point,
that's probably not the most efficient way to achieve it. 
It's easier to just use regular `python` and `pandas` functions.

In most cases, it's more likely to apply a rule to many, many data.